# Google Cloud Run concurrency limits + autoscaling clarifications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Google Cloud Run allows a specified [request concurrency limit](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/concurrency) per container. The subtext of the input field states *"When this concurrency number is reached, a new container instance is started"* Two clarification questions:

1. Is there any way to set Cloud Run to anticipate the concurrency limit being reached, and spawn a new container a little before that happens to ensure that requests over the concurrency limit of Container 1 are seamlessly handled by Container 2 without the cold start time affecting the requests?
2. Imagine we have *Maximum Instances* set to *10*, *Concurrency* set to 10 and there are currently 100 requests being processed (i.e. we've maxed our our capacity and cannot autoscale any more). What happens to the 101th request? Will it be queued up for some period of time, or will a 5XX be returned immediately?

Comment: did you perhaps find a way to get the 429 request (Question 2) returned immediately on max concurrent requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to set Cloud Run to anticipate the concurrency limit
> being reached, and spawn a new container a little before that happens
> to ensure that requests over the concurrency limit of Container 1 are
> seamlessly handled by Container 2 without the cold start time
> affecting the requests?

No. Cloud Run does not try to predict future traffic patterns.

> Imagine we have Maximum Instances set to 10, Concurrency set to 10 and
> there are currently 100 requests being processed (i.e. we've maxed our
> our capacity and cannot autoscale any more). What happens to the 101th
> request? Will it be queued up for some period of time, or will a 5XX
> be returned immediately?

HTTP Error `429 Too Many Requests` will be returned.

[EDIT - Google Cloud documentation on request queuing]

> Under normal circumstances, your revision scales out by creating new
> instances to handle incoming traffic load. But when you set a maximum
> instances limit, in some scenarios there will be insufficient
> instances to meet that traffic load. In that case, incoming requests
> queue for up to 60 seconds. During this 60 second window, if an
> instance finishes processing requests, it becomes available to process
> queued requests. If no instances become available during the 60 second
> window, the request fails with a 429 error code on Cloud Run (fully
> managed).

[About maximum container instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#max-instances)

Comment: do you know if it's possible to have the 429 returned immediately instead of after 60 seconds? If not for CloudRun, perhaps an arthos setup?

Comment: @KevinDanikowski - I am not aware of a method to modify the request queuing behavior. Requests are managed by the GFE (Google Front End) which is a huge system supporting multiple Google services.

Comment: I guess I'm going to just have to code it into the service